# How can I include a 3rd table to a join but not worry if that table has rows that can be joined?

Tags: mysql, join, sqlite

I have a normalized database where tables may or not have information pertaining to other related tables. For example

- word table

  - id
  - value
- definition table

  - id
  - foreignk (to word.id)
  - value
- countryoforigin

  - id
  - foreignk (to definition.id)
  - value

For example here, joining word and definition table is no problem at all but how can I / should I, also join the countryoforigin if the word entry may or may not have a countryoforigin? (This is just one example but I have several other tables in the same situation).

This query works if word.id has a corresponding entry in the countryoforigin table but returns nothing at all if there is no matching entry.

```
select * from word, definition, countryoforigin where
word.id = definition.fk and
word.id = 11 and
countryoforigin.fk = definition.id;
```

Would it be better to just split the query and do a separate select operation on countryoforigin table by itself using a select on countryoforigin.foreignk with definition.id as the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    word
        INNER JOIN
    definition ON word.id = definition.fk
        LEFT JOIN
    countryoforigin ON countryoforigin.fk = definition.id
WHERE
    word.id = 11
```

Answer (score 1):

The operation you describe is called an outer join. Here's Andrew's (correct) answer with the full syntax. The `OUTER` keyword is optional syntactic sugar.

```
SELECT * FROM word INNER JOIN definition ON word.id = definition.fk LEFT OUTER JOIN countryoforigin ON countryoforigin.fk = definition.id WHERE
word.id = 11
```

Note you can specify a left or right outer join. For a left join, result row(s) are produced for each row in the table on the left side of the join expression.  For a right join, result row(s) are produced for each row in the table on the right side of the join expression.

You could just use left joins and flip the tables around.